# fakeredis between multiple django views

Tags: django, python-3.x, redis, fakeredis

I have a test which involve multiple Django views

It seems that the fakeredis isn't shared between multiple views
I tried running the following code:

```
import fakeredis
from testfixtures import Replacer


class TestWithFakeRedis(TestCase):
    def setup_redis(self, test_func):
        fake_redis = fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis()
        with Replacer() as replace:
            replace('app1.views.redis_connection', fake_redis)
            replace("app2.views.redis_connection", fake_redis)
            replace("app2.views.redis_connection", fake_redis)
            test_func(fake_redis)

    def test_something(self):
         def test_func(redis_connection):
            # some testing coded here
            pass
         self.setup_redis(test_func)
```

the fakeredis can't be passed between multiple views and it's something that I need

Thanks in advance,

Nadav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution involved using unittest.mock.patch:

```
import fakeredis
fake_redis = fakeredis.FakeRedis()

@patch("app_name1.views.redis_connection", fake_redis)
@patch("app_name2.views.redis_connection", fake_redis)
@patch("app_name3.views.redis_connection", fake_redis)
class TestSomethingWithRedis(TestCase):
    pass
```

if you want to check query inside your test(s)
use [fake_redis](https://github.com/dsoftwareinc/fakeredis-py)

Comment: And if I need to mock `from django.core.cache import cache` with fake_redis, how the patch will look like?